# Filter csv file, remove lines that only differ in first column (Bash performance)

Tags: bash, csv

I want to filter CSV files, removing lines that only differ in the first column, but keeping the first and the last line of a block with such "duplicate"-lines

I've coded a little bash script that does what I want:

```
nogo="this line is a nogo, replace it!"
prev2=$nogo
prev1=$nogo

function printgo {
  if [ "$1" != "$nogo" ]
  then
    echo "$1"
  fi
} 

while read line ; do
  if [ "$prev1" = "$nogo" ]
  then
    prev1=$line
  else
    prevp=$(echo "$prev1" | sed -e 's/[0-9 :-]*;//')
    linep=$(echo "$line" | sed -e 's/[0-9 :-]*;//')
    if [ "$prevp" != "$linep" ]
    then
      printgo "$prev2"
      printgo "$prev1"
      prev2=$nogo
    else
      prev2p=$(echo "$prev1" | sed -e 's/[0-9 :-]*;//')
      if [[ "$prev2" == "$nogo" || "$prevp" != "$prev2p" ]]
      then
        prev2=$prev1
      fi
    fi
    prev1=$line
  fi
done < <(cat $1)

printgo "$prev2"
printgo "$prev1"
```

Now my question is: How to improve the performance of this thing - without too much work ;)

Comment: I don't have time to answer properly but doing x=$(echo xyz|sed)  will cost a lot of performance execing that for each line. Use bash's built-in parameter substitution instead http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect awk will be faster:

```
awk -F ';' '
    {key = $0; sub("^[^" FS "]+" FS, "", key)}
    key != prev_key {
        if (prev_line != block_start_line) print prev_line
        block_start_line = $0
        print
    }
    {prev_key = key; prev_line = $0}
    END {if (prev_line != block_start_line) print prev_line}
' << END
1;2;3;4
2;2;3;4
3;2;3;4
4;2;3;4
9;8;7;6
8;8;7;6
1;2;3;4
1;8;7;6
2;8;7;6
3;8;7;6
END
```

```
1;2;3;4
4;2;3;4
9;8;7;6
8;8;7;6
1;2;3;4
1;8;7;6
3;8;7;6
```

Comment: yep, thats a lot faster! And it does exactly the same as my script! Though I sure wish I would be able to understand that code..
what does print do if the variable is not set yet? what does the print without anything behind it do?

Comment: ah I think I got it, the print without variable will print $0 = the current line - and it seems when the variable its given is not set print will not print anything (not even a new line).

Comment: ähm correction the print prev_line will only be reached when prev_line is set since as long as prev_line is not set, block_start_line is also not set, therefore it doesn't matter what print will do with an unset variable. thanks for the great and simple and efficient piece of code!